# Kendo Multiselect To have arrow icon and behavior to close on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I am trying to add more functionality to my Kendo Multiselect, in order to behave like a normal dropdown list. I want it to have an arrow or a triangle icon, and to toggle and close on click on that icon. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have tried to implement ng-click multiSelect.close(); ng-if aria expanded... If is Togle multiSelect.close(); so to have it on filed like this... I don't know how to pass a button on field with this functionality... I need some ideas or maybe possible solution. And only solution for getting arrow icon was in css 
.k-multiselect-wrap{  
    background: url(images/dropdowntriangle.png) no-repeat  right center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question comes up quite high on Google for "kendo multiselect arrow". Here's a more complete solution I'm using. (The CSS Manuel answered with is fine - it's actually from my post on the Telerik forums!).

CSS to add a dropdown arrow:

```
.k-multiselect:after {
content: "\25BC";
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
right: 25px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Trickery to make it a sideways facing arrow when opened:

**CSS**

```
.k-multiselect.opened:after {
content: "\25C0";
}
```

**JS**

```
var Globals = {};

$('#foo').kendoMultiSelect({
    ...
    open: function(){
       $(this.element).parent().addClass('opened'); // ▼ becomes ◀
       Globals.MultiSelectIsOpening = true;
       setTimeout(function(){
           Globals.MultiSelectIsOpening = false;
       }, 100);
    },
    close: function(){
        $(this.element).parent().removeClass('opened');
    }
    ...
});

$('#foo_container').on('click', '.k-multiselect', function () {
    if (!Globals.MultiSelectIsOpening) {
        $('#foo').data('kendoMultiSelect').toggle();
    }
});
```

`#foo_container` can be worked out dynamically needs be - `$('#foo').parents('.k-multiselect').parent()`, for example.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/Hd47F/105/) demonstrating it working. The only problem  I've found so far is that it'll cause the list items to be closed when you delete an item from the multiselect.

Until [kendo add this as a feature](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/11051628-allow-us-to-display-a-dropdown-arrow-on-a-kendomul), I think this is the best we can do!

Edit - sorry, not Angular - HTH nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. I have already solve this with AngularJS but still it is very helpful.

Comment: A more complete answer, I will delete mine :)

Comment: @error505 would be cool if you shared how you solved it with Angular!

Comment: I will try to find my old code somewhere and I will post the angular solution asap.